d3 doesn't work in vue3 composition mode in single file component (SFC) written by typescript
here is a vue3 single file component (SFC) in composition mode written by typescript.
I save it as a .vue file which is a vue3 SFC, and integrate it into a vue3 project.
<template>
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ref="svgElement" class="center-plot-graph">
            <g ref="lineElement" class="lineElements">
                <path class="splineElement" />
                <g class="symbolElement" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
    select,
    Selection,
    scaleLinear,
    ScaleLinear,
    symbol,
    symbolCircle,
    line,
    Line,
    curveLinear,
    ValueFn,
    BaseType,
} from "d3";
// import * as d3 from "d3"
import { ref, Ref, inject, onMounted } from "vue";

type Vector1d = Array<number>;
type Vector2d = Array<Vector1d>;

const svgElement: Ref<SVGSVGElement | null> = ref<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);
const lineElement: Ref<SVGGElement | null> = ref<SVGGElement | null>(null);

let lineData1: Vector2d = [
    [10.5, 0, -26.5, 1],
    [10.515418023668452, 0, -25.98615240945993, 0.9999999999999999],
    [10.54673612522916, 0, -25.4242010779106, 0.9999999999999998],
    [10.599262000092798, 0, -24.79828284532514, 0.9999999999999998],
    [10.682246533999162, 0, -24.080779736377877, 0.9999999999999999],
    [10.814880527142483, 0, -23.214463145842437, 0.9999999999999998],
    [11.054647461420542, 0, -22.028119146822945, 0.9999999999999999],
    [11.671811400028488, 0, -19.86283988201097, 0.9999999999999998],
    [12.613086386434938, 0, -17.545566003251505, 0.9999999999999999],
    [13.813926262485333, 0, -15.363942341711933, 1],
    [15.263842352648265, 0, -13.35830776532418, 1.0000000000000004],
    [16.93791350677736, 0, -11.540160490114632, 1.0000000000000007],
    [18.800820600423645, 0, -9.900220288676735, 1.0000000000000004],
    [20.817015127495804, 0, -8.428748556487237, 1.0000000000000004],
    [22.9509485819025, 0, -7.116006689022895, 1.0000000000000002],
    [25.16710035838422, 0, -5.9522535772986, 1],
    [27.437849524060642, 0, -4.927039014178517, 0.9999999999999999],
    [29.7542920863866, 0, -4.028232704145715, 0.9999999999999999],
    [32.11023490194244, 0, -3.243461017781614, 0.9999999999999998],
    [34.499484827308535, 0, -2.56035032566763, 0.9999999999999997],
    [36.91584871906518, 0, -1.9665269983851892, 0.9999999999999996],
    [39.35328336132695, 0, -1.4504051633262336, 0.9999999999999997],
    [41.8071311282343, 0, -1.0076791848683684, 0.9999999999999999],
    [44.273483525476955, 0, -0.6379795521514762, 1],
    [46.499497521985354, 0, -0.3675404908536285, 0.9999999999999998],
    [47.70003443876498, 0, -0.24619654497075863, 1],
    [48.571814387462624, 0, -0.16874721429387524, 0.9999999999999999],
    [49.292111379398605, 0, -0.11149361650523448, 1],
    [49.91998747855483, 0, -0.06654412557289584, 1],
    [50.483859148305946, 0, -0.03010369508701564, 1.0000000000000002],
    [51, 0, 0, 1],
];
let lineData2: Vector2d = [
    [10.5, 0, -26.5, 1],
    [10.573820291076342, 0, -22.314239546778368, 0.9999999999999995],
    [13.359019071367536, 0, -13.451591871333579, 1.0000000000000007],
    [24.504724058628779, 0, -5.452588866468975, 1.0000000000000003],
    [37.471579656269877, 0, -1.4571818281579628, 0.9999999999999992],
    [46.497084577993259, 0, -0.24908378543712748, 1.0000000000000003],
    [51, 0, 0, 1],
];

let xScale: ScaleLinear<number, number, never> = scaleLinear()
    .domain([-26, 0])
    .range([10, 920]);
let yScale: ScaleLinear<number, number, never> = scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 52])
    .range([10, 950]);

// let rootNode: Selection<SVGSVGElement, Vector2d, null, undefined> = select<SVGSVGElement, Vector2d>(svgElement.value as SVGSVGElement)
let splineElement: Selection<SVGPathElement, Vector2d, null, undefined> =
    select(lineElement.value as SVGGElement)
        .select<SVGPathElement>(".splineElement")
        .datum<Vector2d>(lineData1)
        .attr(
            "d",
            (
                d: Vector2d,
                i: number,
                a: Array<SVGPathElement> | ArrayLike<SVGPathElement>
            ) => {
                return line<Vector1d>()
                    .x((di: Vector1d, ii: number, ao: Vector2d) => xScale(di[2]))
                    .y((di: Vector1d, ii: number, ao: Vector2d) => yScale(di[0]))
                    .curve(curveLinear)(d);
            }
        )
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "none");

let SymbolTransform: ValueFn<SVGPathElement | BaseType, Vector1d, string> =
    function (
        d: Vector1d,
        i: number,
        a: Array<BaseType | SVGPathElement> | ArrayLike<BaseType | SVGPathElement>
    ): string {
        const x = xScale(d[2]);
        const y = yScale(d[0]);
        return `translate(${x},${y})`;
    };

let symbolNode: Selection<SVGPathElement, Vector1d, SVGGElement, Vector2d> =
    select(lineElement.value as SVGGElement)
        .select<SVGPathElement>(".symbolElement")
        .selectAll<SVGPathElement, Vector1d>("path")
        .data<Vector1d>(lineData2)
        .join("path")
        .attr("d", symbol<Vector1d>(symbolCircle, 20))
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .attr("transform", SymbolTransform);
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
.center-plot-graph {
    position: absolute;
    width: 936px;
    height: 960px;
}
</style>


the dependencies are:
"dependencies": {
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "vue": "^3.4.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "eslint": "^9.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.25.0",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vite-plugin-top-level-await": "^1.4.1",
    "vitest": "^1.5.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.6"
  }

it should display a smooth curve and some symbols, but it displays nothing.
I checked the internal component of the DOM, the innerHTML of the DOM is nothing. So that means d3 didn't generate anything in the DOM.
Can anybody help me to check the error of my code?

There is quite some code here, maybe try to narrow it down to 1 simple element first, will help you troubleshoot the whole thing. Otherwise, look for errors in the console.

thank you for your proposal. I've checked, this is the most simple code, I've already removed all useless code. And this code passed the typescript type checking, there is no error hint. This is the reason why I feel very confused.

TS will only error for a type error, not for a "logic/setup" error. So your code could not work with a green TS, while you could have a red TS and your code working well. I'd rather focus on the functionality first and fix the types later on, especially if you're not at ease with TS or d3. Focus on the important part first.

I've simplified the logic, it's the most simple now. There are 2 sets of [y, 0, x, 1] points data, plot lineData1 as smooth line, and plot lineData2 as symbols. In template, the DOM tree is defined. In script, the 1st step is to import definitions, the 2nd step is to define the sample data, the 3rd step is to define the d3.scale for x and y, the 4th step is to plot the smooth line, the 5th step is to plot the symbols with transform. Because of d3.js internal mechanism, I can't use line by line debug to see what happens in attr("d", (d, i, a)=>{}), it's a headache.

I would like to help you buddy but I do not have any d3 experience as of today. Maybe giving a look to something like this could help? https://blog.logrocket.com/data-visualization-vue-js-d3/ Try to find any kind of boilerplate where there is already some code that's working.

I don't know anything about vue.js but I'm assuming this compiles to out to standard HTML/JS and that you aren't getting errors during that compile.   So, does the browser throw any console errors when you load the resulting HTML/JS?

actually, there is no error/warning in the console. Even I add some console.log(message) in the attr("d", (d, i, a)=>{}), there is still no output. This is the reason why I can't debug. It's really headache for me.
